# Can not Create Samba Directory Android

Tags: android, android-studio, share, samba, jcifs

I am new to android and i just want to take a picture from my Android and save it to a share folder at my pc,
this was a simple task and i have accomplished this but now I am stuck at this that i want to create a folder first for example,
myserver/share
i don't want to place pics here, i want to create a new folder like this
myserver/share/new folder

And i want all my pics go into this new folder, So far i have tried this code

```
                 try
                    {
                        String url = "smb://serverpath/share/"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"/Test.jpg";
                        SmbFile smfile = null;
                        try {
                            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth =new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain","myuser","pass");

                            smfile = new SmbFile(url, auth);
                            if(!smfile.exists())
                            {
                               smfile.mkdirs();
                            }
                            // output is like smb://mypc/e/sharedfoldername/file.txt;
                            SmbFileOutputStream out = new SmbFileOutputStream(smfile);
                            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                            out.write(byteArray);
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            e.getCause();
                        }
```

but I am getting a path not found exception below,

```
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:         jcifs.smb.SmbException: The system cannot find the path specified.
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:545)
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:645)
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:230)
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:770)
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.mkdir(SmbFile.java:2511)
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at com.test.test.cameraapplication.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:180)
09-20 12:01:21.691 18341-19275/com.test.test.cameraapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved this, I don't know if it is a proper solution or not but still i will share this i just removed the file name from URL and it created a directory and after that i appended file to this directory

Like this

```
                        String url = "smb://myserver/share/"+ edittext.getText().toString();
                        SmbFile smfile = null;
                        try {
                            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth =new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain","user","password");

                            smfile = new SmbFile(url, auth);
                            if(!smfile.exists())
                            {
                               smfile.mkdirs();
                            }
                            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                            url = "smb://myserver/share/"+ edittext.getText().toString()+"/IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg";
```